# Why isn't a Decimal an instance of the Real number abstract base class?

Tags: python

The python `Decimal` object is not currently specified a subclass of the `Real` abstract base class:

```py
from numbers import Real
from decimal import Decimal

isinstance(Decimal("1.0"), numbers.Real) #  False
```

This is easily changed by registering `Decimal` as a subclass:

```
Real.register(Decimal)
```

But it makes me ask the question: why is `Decimal` not registered this way to begin with? Is there some practical reason, or design reason, that it would be a bad idea to make this assumption about decimal instances?

Comment: I think you can just take this as a sign of how low adoption of those ABCs is.

Comment: @user2357112 fair point. i'm the only person on the planet i've even seen try to make use of them.

Comment: i swear i searched for this question and did not find anything. how did i miss that duplicate? ah well.

Answer (score 4):

Answer is in [`numbers` module](https://docs.python.org/library/numbers.html) source:

```
## Notes on Decimal
## ----------------
## Decimal has all of the methods specified by the Real abc, but it should
## not be registered as a Real because decimals do not interoperate with
## binary floats (i.e.  Decimal('3.14') + 2.71828 is undefined).  But,
## abstract reals are expected to interoperate (i.e. R1 + R2 should be
## expected to work if R1 and R2 are both Reals).
```

they probably can add this to docs, I think.

Comment: The source code line `503` says basically the same thing as well: [_pydecimal.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/_pydecimal.py). But it references `numbers` which you pasted above.